# How to clear a line on Mac OS Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

The above table shows that `Esc[2K` clears a line.

But on Mac Terminal, I don't see the line is cleard.

```
$ echo abc$'\e[2k'
abc
```

The TERM variable is the following.

```
$ declare -p TERM
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
```

Does anybody how to clear a line? (If possible, it should work on other terminals as well other than Mac Terminal.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just wager it as minor typo, because the escape sequence associated with clearing a line is `Esc[2K` with an upper case `K` and not `k`

```
echo -e abc$'\e[2K'
```

should work just as expected. Note that `echo -e` and the ANSI C style escapes (`$'...'`) are `bash` shell specific and non POSIX conformant. You can always use `printf()` that supports escape sequences too

```
printf abc'\e[2K'
```

Also the escape character notation `\e` may *not* be supported in all versions of `echo`, but the only the `bash` built-in provided. You could use the hex equivalent of `\e` as `\x1B` or an octal equivalent of `\033`.